# MsSql get a blank record based on structure

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, datatable

is there a way to receive back from `SHOW COLUMNS FROM xxtable` a blank record with the fields from the table?

Currently, I can get a record return if my search criteria is met - when doing:

```
SELECT * FROM xxtable WHERE fieldA = "blah"
```

But if there is no match, I would like to receive an 'empty' record - not null but with the values being blank.

I am making the call from within a PHP function back to JavaScript so I need the return to provide a record in JSON format.

I can check to see if nothing is returned from the select, but was wondering if there is then a way to create an empty record with the right field names all in one each step.

Comment: The SHOW COLUMNS command returns enough information about the fields in the table to build, and return, the appropriate data/record.

Comment: i just wasn't sure if i could use a single select statement to provide a record instead of using the structure and then looping through to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want:

```
if not exists(SELECT * FROM xxtable WHERE fieldA = 'blah')
begin
    select ''
end
else
begin
    SELECT * FROM xxtable WHERE fieldA = 'blah'
end
```

Or maybe you want...

```
if not exists(SELECT * FROM xxtable WHERE fieldA = 'blah')
begin
    select 
        column1 = ''
        ,column2 = ''
        ....
end
else
begin
    SELECT * FROM xxtable WHERE fieldA = 'blah'
end
```

Comment: I beleive the OP wants every column to contain `''`, not a single (unmamed column) with the value `''`.

Comment: that sounds about it...I get either the actual data (if found) or a record based on the table structure with blank values for each field

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. What you would expect for a column of the data type `date`? what about an `int` or a `decimal`? `''` is neither a date or number, but it would be implicitly cast to the column's data type. For example:

```
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '';
```

Notice that the `''` returns 0, not `''` or `NULL`. That's because `CONVERT(int,'') = 0`. For a `date` then the value `19000101` would be returned:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,'20180101')
UNION ALL
SELECT '';
```

You could therefore do something like

```
SELECT '' AS [Column1Name],
       '' AS [Column2Name],
       '' AS [Column3Name],
       '' AS [Column4Name],
       ...
```

However, the problem with this is if the columns in your underlying tables changes, this won't be reflective. The fact, also, that the column data types aren't reflective isn't a great idea either.

Honestly, i think you need to work out how to handle a dataset with no rows in your presentation layer, not try and around it by creating a bad dataset.

Comment: yeah, i want them set appropriately for their data types...just not with a value - for example, a date would be all zeroes in date format.

Comment: @user3861284 `00/00/0000` is not a date, and cannot be converted to a `date` datatype, as it's a nonsensical value.